# How to get user order data by specific month in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I want to user orders data by specific month in a year.

Here is my order Table

id | user_id | price | quantity | total

Here is my order model

```
 public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Here is my user model

```
 public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

In a controller, by doing this I get all user orders

```
 $user= User::with('orders')->get();
 dd($user->orders);
```

Now, How can I get specific month user orders detail?
I want to show all user list with their order's total amount by month.

Comment: Have a look at the [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method.

Comment: If you're only wanting to get the orders for those specific months as well, you should look at [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get users with their orders' total of September:

```php
$users = User::withSum(['orders as september_total' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereMonth('created_at', '9'); // September
}, 'total'])->get();
```

This will place a `september_total` attribute on your resulting models.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these two queries:

```php
$users = User::query()->with(['orders' => function($q){
    $q->whereRaw('MONTH(orders.created_at) = 2');
}])->get();

// eager load all orders that have been created on month 2

$users = User::query()->whereHas('orders', function($q){
    $q->whereRaw('MONTH(orders.created_at) = 2');
})->get();

// you'll get all users with orders on month 2 (no eager loading)
```

You can of course combine `with` (eager load) and `whereHas` (filter users) in order to "only get the users that have orders on month 2 AND eager load those orders".

Of course, feel free to use another column (e.g. `ordered_at`) or change the month if you need to.